# SpriteKit - CGRects, Sprites, Touch - Nothing working so far

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, cgrect

I'm basically looking to perform an action once a sprite is touched. This is my code so far, but currently it does not seem to be performing the function i need. Can anyone spot anything? Thanks

NB: The code sets up a lattice of dots, with rectangular sprites in between the dots that should represent touch areas. i.e when one of the touch areas is touched, and action is performed. If my explanation of what this looks like is poor, please refer to this:

http://cl.ly/image/1W1e263B2b08/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-20%20at%2020.43.17.png

```
#define kRowCount 8
#define kColCount 6
#define kDotGridSpacing CGSizeMake (50,-50)
#import "BBMyScene.h"

@implementation BBMyScene

@synthesize dot;
@synthesize htoucharea;
@synthesize vtoucharea;




-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    //  Set up Background
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.957 green:0.957 blue:0.957 alpha:1]; /*#f4f4f4*/


    // Set up Lattice of Dots
    CGPoint baseOrigin = CGPointMake(35, 385);
    for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < kRowCount; ++row) {


        CGPoint dotPosition = CGPointMake(baseOrigin.x, row * (kDotGridSpacing.height) + baseOrigin.y);


        for (NSUInteger col = 0; col < kColCount; ++col) {

            dot = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dot"];
            dot.position = dotPosition;
            NSString *dotName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dot_%d_%d", row, col];
            dot.name = dotName;
            [self addChild:dot];
            dotPosition.x += kDotGridSpacing.width;



        }

    }


    //Set up horizontal touch areas
    for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < kRowCount; ++row) {

        CGPoint htouchareaPosition = CGPointMake(baseOrigin.x + 0.5*(kDotGridSpacing.width), row * (kDotGridSpacing.height) + baseOrigin.y);

        for (NSUInteger col = 0; col < kColCount-1; ++col) {

            htoucharea = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.702 blue:0.91 alpha:0.5] size:CGSizeMake(35,25)];
            htoucharea.position = htouchareaPosition;
            NSString *htouchareaName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"htoucharea_%d_%d", row, col];
            htoucharea.name = htouchareaName;
            htoucharea.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            htouchareaPosition.x += kDotGridSpacing.width;

            [self addChild:htoucharea];


        }

    }







    // Set up vertical touch areas
    for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < kRowCount-1; ++row) {

        CGPoint vtouchareaPosition = CGPointMake(baseOrigin.x, row * (kDotGridSpacing.height) + baseOrigin.y + 0.5*(kDotGridSpacing.height));

        for (NSUInteger col = 0; col < kColCount; ++col) {

            vtoucharea = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.478 blue:0.478 alpha:0.5] size:CGSizeMake(25,35)];
            vtoucharea.position = vtouchareaPosition;
            NSString *vtouchareaName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vtoucharea_%d_%d", row, col];
            vtoucharea.name = vtouchareaName;
            vtoucharea.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [self addChild:vtoucharea];
            vtouchareaPosition.x += kDotGridSpacing.width;


        }

    }



}

return self;
}

-(CGRect)getSpriteRect:(SKNode *)inSprite
{
CGRect sprRect = CGRectMake(htoucharea.position.x, htoucharea.position.y, 35, 25);


return sprRect;
}





- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
// get the touch
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

// get the location of the touch in the main view of the view controller
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

CGRect hRect = [self getSpriteRect:htoucharea];


if (CGRectContainsPoint(hRect, touchPoint))
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your htoucharea pointer is only going to point to the last h sprite you made. This code may work on one sprite. Not sure without testing it. You can either put all your sprites into an array and test each one's rect against the touch point, or you can subclass sprites and have each one report if they have been touched.

The array method is likely easier to figure out. When you create each sprite, add it to a mutable array property. Then you'll have them to test against.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and answer!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've taken into account the fact that `SKSpriteNode` is a descendant of `UIResponder` and have the sprites themselves register the touches via `touchesBegan: withEvent:` I have implemented the whole thing with a delegate pattern where the scene acts as the sprites' delegates. Then inside my sprite subclass I simply have:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.delegate touchesBeganOnSprite:self];
}
```

then inside my scene I can:

```
- (void)touchesBeganOnSprite:(SKSpriteNode *)sprite{
    // do whatever I like with the sprite...
}
```

You could of course use the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` without using the delegate pattern as well. Either by using notifications or by performing selector/method-calls on the node's `scene` property. (I personally believe the delegate pattern is the way to go though).